# Jenkins Pipeline: How to configure Polling ignores commits in certain paths?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-git-plugin

we are currently setting up CI/CD Pipelines for our microfrontend projects. These projects are in one repository. We want to setup a pipeline for every project. Our plan is to use the Polling ignores commits in certain paths setting from the git Plugin to prevent building the pipeline when commits are pushed outside of the project folder or when the deployment file is changed. The deployment file will be changed an pushed to the repo in a pipeline step. Now the pipeline is in a loop because our settings doesnt seem to work. Did we configuere somethink wrong?

These are the pipeline settings:

[Build triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4qpS.png)

[Pipeline settings 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5yoV.png)

[Pipeline settings 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq0P3.png)

And this is the Jenkinsfile:

````
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml '''
        // kubernetes yaml
        '''
    }
  }
  stages {
        stage('Checkout from SCM') {
          steps {
            container('node') {
              git branch: '[BRANCH]', credentialsId: '[CREDENTIAL_ID]', url: '[URL]'
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Build docker-image and push to registry') {
            steps {
                container('node') {
                  dir("frontend/shell") {
                    withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: '[CREDENTIAL_ID]', url: "[URL]"]) {
                      // build steps
                    }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Remove Recent Image from Node') {
          steps {
            container('node') {
              sh "docker rmi [IMAGE_NAME]:v1.2.1.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Edit deploymentDev.yaml') {
          steps {
            container('node') {
              script {
                def yamlFilePath = 'frontend/shell/deployment/deploymentDev.yaml'
                def newImage = "[IMAGE_NAME]:v1.2.1.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                sh "sed -i 's|image:.*|image: ${newImage}|' ${yamlFilePath}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage ('Deploy to Test-Cluster') {
          steps {
            container('node') {
              dir("frontend/shell/deployment") {
                sh 'kubectl apply -f deploymentDev.yaml'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        stage('Commit Changes to deployment file') {
          steps {
            container('node') {
              withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '[CREDENTIAL_ID]', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
                  // commit and push
              }
            }
          }
        }
  }
  post {
        // post steps
    }
}```


We checked the documentation of the git plugin and think this configuration should work.
````

Comment: A solution is to not do this ignore in the pipeline but in the Jenkins job configuration -> Branch Sources -> Build strategies -> Ignore Committer Strategy and add the email address of the ignored committer.
Beware, this will ignore the committer on all branches, and maybe this is not what you want.